# Joomla 4 does not send emails to users after registration

Tags: joomla-4.x, registration, user-registration

On a new Joomla 4 site, I activated user registration, with profile activation via link sent by email.

In the tests I did, I found that new users do not receive the email with the activation link.
I have already checked the config settings for sending php/smtp messages.
Furthermore, the site administrator correctly receives the email of the new registered user.

I need help solving this problem. Can anyone who already faced this problem help me?

Thanks

Comment: In your hosting account have you checked whether the email has been sent and if it was received or rejected? In cPanel the feature is in the Email group and is called Track Delivery. This will help you determine if it is an issue with Joomla, your email server or the recipients.

Comment: Hi, the settings on the server are correct, the strange thing is that if I register a user, the email arrives to the administrator, but it doesn't reach the new user.
Could it be a Joomla bug?

Comment: I wasn't asking to check settings. If you use a 'Track Delivery' feature, or whatever it is for your hosting/server account, then you should be able to see if the email to the user actually left Joomla and appeared on the Mail server as outgoing mail. If you can see the email got to the mail server then it is probably not a Joomla issue and it is an email delivery issue. If it doesn't appear to have reached the mail server then turn on messages, Error Reporting, and see if there are any further diagnostics available.

Comment: Hi, I haven't cpanel, but another panel. The setting is right.

Comment: The fact that the site admin gets the email makes this unlikely to be a Joomla issue.  As mentioned, check your email logs.  It would be useful if you can provide the administrator success data along with the user success or failure data.

Comment: Hi, I solved. there was misconfiguration dmarc and spf in DNS record

Comment: @Joso Stack Exchange pages must not be resolved via comment.  Please post an informative answer to your question and then you will be able to award it the green tick to signify that this page is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emails are probably going to the spam folder. Check the settings in your DNS records.